# One image from file and 4 text fields from MySQL database into PDF using FPDF

Tags: image, text, fpdf

The MySQL database has over 100 rows. The first field in the table is the image file location and the rest of the fields are text for a total of 5 fields per line.
I can get all the text from the table using
$pdf->Table($link,'select image, description, code, size, units from sheet order by ID',$prop);
but I cannot get the image in nor wrap the text fields in the cells.
I think I have to use the 'cell' method instead but I am really stuck as to the way forward.
Any help and example on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code at here

Comment: You could try [fpdf-easyTable](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Here is the code so far. It says it is too long to add so I am just putting in the last few lines after connecting to the Db.

Comment: //$pdf = new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.1);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(242, 242, 242);
//$pdf->SetWidths(array(30, 50, 30, 40));
$pdf->AddCol('image',-1,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('description',-1,'Description');
$pdf->AddCol('code',-1,'Code','C');
$pdf->AddCol('size',-1,'Size','C');
$pdf->AddCol('units',-1,'Units','C');
$prop = array('HeaderColor'=>array(242,242,242),
   'color1'=>array(255,255,255),
   //'color2'=>array(255,255,255),
   'padding'=>.5);
$pdf->Table($link,'select image, description, code, size, units from sheet order by ID',$prop);
$pdf->Output();

Comment: The `PDF_MC_Table` class doesn't support images, so you will need to modify it.

Comment: Oliver, that line is commented out. I am using `$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');